# What makes this CSS animation change color gradually?

Tags: html, css

I came across this CSS animation on w3schools:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation3

the code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: myfirst 5s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: myfirst 5s;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
    0%   {background:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
    25%  {background:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
    50%  {background:blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
    75%  {background:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
    100% {background:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes myfirst {
    0%   {background:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
    25%  {background:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
    50%  {background:blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
    75%  {background:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
    100% {background:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p><b>Note:</b> This example does not work in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

It's obvious that red,yellow,blue and green colors are specified in the CSS. But what makes it change the color gradually? from red to yellow and so on?

thanks in advance.

Comment: i don't understand a down vote here....it seems some people sit creep around on SO for downvoting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well obviously, you can see the percentages:

```
@keyframes myfirst {
0%   {background:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
25%  {background:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
50%  {background:blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
75%  {background:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
100% {background:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}
```

and a duration specified with the animation:

```
animation: myfirst 5s;
/*-----------------^ animation duration*/
```

This means, The animation will start with (`0%`) `red` background, it'll gradually move towards the next frame which is defined at `25%` (*Yellow*) once the animation reaches `25%` of the specified duration, it'll become `yellow`, once the duration reaches `50%` it'll become `blue` and so on.

[More about keyframes @MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)

Comment: but why the colors in the middle like light green and so on?

Comment: @peter_ziegler because it is an **animation**. For example, if you specify `left:200px` at `25%`, the element will not sit where it is and suddenly jump to that position when it reaches `25%` of duration. It'll animate **gradually** from the current value to the new one over time. Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

It is the `@keyframes` that is causing it to change the color
here a color is specified at each percentage of the animation so it changes as it moves

```
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
0%   {background:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
25%  {background:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
50%  {background:blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
75%  {background:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
100% {background:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It' the keyframes "functions" : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

Answer (score 1):

this is a feature of `CSS3` called [`animations`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations). [browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=keyframes) that support `CSS3 animations` know how to create transitions based on the rules defined in keyframes.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a CSS rule for all your `div` tags. It has an initial `background` of `red` and has an animation called `myFirst`, where `5s` is specified as a duration. So your animation lasts for five seconds. These rules specify your actual animation behavior:

```
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
    0%   {background:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
    25%  {background:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
    50%  {background:blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
    75%  {background:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
    100% {background:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes myfirst {
    0%   {background:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
    25%  {background:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
    50%  {background:blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
    75%  {background:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
    100% {background:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}
```

0% means we are in the first second. 25% means we are in the second second. 50% means we are in the third second. 75% means we are in the fourth second. 100% means we are at the end of the animation, that is, we are in the fifth second. So each second a new `background` is given to your `divs`.